# The relationship between $|a^H b|$ and $|a^H W^H W b|$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there are two vectors $ a \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}^N$ such that $|a^H b| \le \rho$ where $a^H $ means the conjugate transpose of $a$, and $\rho\in[0,1]$ is a constant. Given a matrix $W\in  \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ with each elements being $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\{-1,+1\}$ with equal probability, is there any relationship between $|a^H b|$ and $|a^H W^H W b$|?

Comment: I think many symbols need to be explained. Does $C$ mean the complex number field? If the answer is yes, then you should use $\mathbb{C}$. To see code you can select it, right click, and then tap "Show Math As" "TeX Commands". And what is $a^H$

Comment: $a^H$ means the conjugate transpose of the vector $a$. I have revised the question.

Comment: Hint: $W^{H}W$ is diagonally dominant. Thus, you can approximate it to a diagonal matrix.